# Setting up virtualhost in APache

Tags: apache

Im trying to setup the virtualhost in my apache server and its not working as expected.

First, it all works fine if I try localhost..but when I try www.test.com it does take me to the actual website..How do I register my changes?

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/apache-virtual-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/Deployment/wsgi.py
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        #AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the platform? windows? Linux? Guess test.com is not registered by yoy.

Comment: Its on Linux..Yes, test.com is not registered ...Where should I make the change...

Comment: @userX - test.com is registered. But just edit /etc/hosts as described below for testing

Answer (score 1):

try to change your hosts file and add www.test.com as local,edit the file with root permission

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1    www.test.com
127.0.0.1    test.com
```

i hope it is helpfull

Comment: Can do it on one line. i.e. `127.0.0.1 www.test.com test.com`